# Creating a terminal device for interprocess communication

Tags: linux, terminal, devices, tty, ipc

I'd like to know how to create a terminal device to simulate a piece of hardware connected through a serial port. Basically, tty device with a certain baud rate that can be read from and written to between two processes. From what I understand, a psuedo-terminal is what I'm looking for, and the `makedev` can apparently make one.

I've also found the following set of instructions:

```
su to root
cd /dev
mkdir pty
mknod pty/m0 c 2 0
mknod pty/s0 c 3 0
ln -s pty/m0 ttyp0
ln -s pty/s0 ptyp0
chmod a+w pty/m0 pty/s0
```

Is there a better way of making pseudo-terminal, or is this pretty much the standard way of make one in the shell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's probably how pty device files get created, but you don't want to do that whenever you want a pty. Any given machine usually has a complement of pty device files already created.

Pseudo TTYs are fairly OS specific and you don't mention what you want to do this on. For a modern linux, I'd take a look at `openpty(3)`.  You can find working example code in the OpenSSH source code, [sshpty.c](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/ssh/sshpty.c?rev=1.28&content-type=text/plain).  You will probably have to find code that calls `pty_allocate()` to fully understand.